# Postgres: Extracting the IDs and names of people who are cheating the system

Tags: postgresql

I have a table A with the following transaction data:

```
ID  Name    Type    
1   Albert  Rewards
2   Albert  Visit
3   Ruddy   Rewards
4   Ruddy   Visit
5   Ruddy   Purchase
6   Mario   Rewards
7   Mario   Visit
     ...
```

I want a table that only select the rows with names of people who used the "Rewards" and "Visit" type but didn't make a purchase, something like this:

```
ID  Name    Type
1   Albert  Rewards
2   Albert  Visit
6   Mario   Rewards
7   Mario   Visit
     ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query will count for every Visit/Rewards/Purchase how often they happened for a given name - and if the respective results are 1/1/0 then all records from the table with that name will be returned.
If fine-tuning is required (such as cases where the count of any of those > 1 etc.) that can be done by fiddling with the numbers in the 'having' clause.  The same is true for adding additional categories to check against.

```
select *
from mytable a
where exists (select b.name, 
                 sum(case when b.type='Rewards' then 1 else 0 end),
                 sum(case when b.type='Visit' then 1 else 0 end),
                 sum(case when b.type='Purchase' then 1 else 0 end)
          from mytable b
          where b.name=a.name
          group by b.name
          having sum(case when b.type='Rewards' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
             and
                 sum(case when b.type='Visit' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
             and
                 sum(case when b.type='Purchase' then 1 else 0 end) = 0);
```

For completion sake: [SQLFiddle with 2 queries First query also works, but a little differently](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/91bba/2)